# How to use Node.js with IPv6?

Tags: node.js, ipv6

Basically, I'd like to know how can I change my server.js code in order for it to work with IPv6? I read somewhere that you only need to add your IPv6 address right next to the line where it says "listen(80)" which would make it look something like this  "listen (80, "IPv6");"

In my code, however, it's a little bit more complicated than that.

Here are the lines of code related to the server:

```
const 

server = http.createServer(options, app),
                   .
                   .
                   .
var ss=tls.createServer(options, function (box) {
    box.setEncoding('utf8');
                   .
                   .


         ss.listen(8010);
              .
              .


var sockets = require('socket.io').listen(server).of('/el');
                   .
                   .
                   .
if (!module.parent) {
  server.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Listening', this.address());
  })
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This works here:

```
http = require('http')

server = http.createServer()
server.listen(8080, '::', function() {
    console.log('listener');
});
```

Then testing it:

```
$ telnet ::1 8080
Trying ::1...
Connected to ::1.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Comment: I was able to make it work by adding these two lines of code:
var v6 = require('ipv6').v6;
var address = new v6.Address('MY IPv6 Address');

And it worked fine, but then out of nowhere, I'm no longer able to access it again. What could be the problem?

Comment: Can you provide more info? Like updating the question with your new code or, maybe closing this question and opening another?

Comment: A socket bound to `::` can receive both IPv4 and IPv6 connections. This does however depend on socket options.